# how to use merge fields in a template

Tags: visualforce, merge

I am trying to mimic the use merge fields used in email templates to something custom for my application.

I am looking at ways for templating content to send sms. The api requires me to provide the body of the content as string. When i do pass the content as a string to API it does work fine. I am thinking of creating a template with merge fields and using that template to send the content.

For eg.

Hi {!Contact.name}

should generate the text

> Hi John

What would be the best way of doing this? Any pointers on how to achieve this would be helpful

Answer (score 4):

```
String mailbdy=c.Campaign.Email_Template__r.HtmlContent__c;
mailbdy=mailbdy.replace('{!CampaignMember.Id}',c.id);
```

Assuming i have stored the Html content in an Email Template Object(field is long text) ,then i can have a query identifying Id from URL parameter if its a visualforce page and then simply use string.Replace() method  to replace with fields value.

May be a utility method to replace necessary fields .